# Can't style submit button with css

Tags: html, css, button, submit

I am trying to make a flask login screen. Flask requires a type="submit" button. Using CSS to style the button does not work. The same code with type="button" works but then flask does not recognize the request.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style2.css" type="text/css">

    <title>Login</title>
    </head>

    <body oncontextmenu="return false">

        <div class="body"></div>
        <div class="grad"></div>
        <div class="header">
        <div>XOR-<span>House</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="login">
            <form action = "/login/" method = "POST">
                <p><input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="userid"></p>
                <p><input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="ps"></p>
                <p><input type ="submit" value ="login" ></p>
            </form>
        </div>
        </body> 
</html>
```

CSS styling

```
.login input[type=submit]{
    width: 260px;
    height: 35px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #a18d6c;
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 6px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.login input[type=submit]:hover{
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.login input[type=submit]:active{
    opacity: 0.6;
}



.login input[type=submit]:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: inputs can be funny. Have you tried just adding a class to the element itself? That is what I normally do.

Comment: add quotes to make it **input[type="submit"]**

Comment: styles are applying on the submit button, what's the exact issue

Comment: try removing .login before or use a comma, and follow @TemaniAfif

Comment: i have tried both of your answers, but they do not work. the issue is that the CSS styling does not apply on the submit button

Comment: I copied your code into a jsfiddle and the button is styled accurately. Possibly a browser issue? I'm on latest Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to ctrl+f5 / clear browser cache ? it seems to be cache issue in this scenario. when you do request from another address, it will pull the latest css instead of referring to browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer! The problem was that we accessed the site from local host, not the ip! When we accessed the site from ip, the submit button was styled! Can anyone explain why that happens?

Answer (score 0):

your example is working the problem could be somewhere else like another style overriding your style. try changing the background because a white background isn't helping itself

```
    .login input[type="submit"] {
    width: 260px;
    height: 35px;
    background: #5bf3e5;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #a18d6c;
    font-family: "Exo", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 6px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

[your code on codepen](https://codepen.io/Laassari/pen/gGWQmr?editors=1100)